# finding user specific data with mixpanel API and PHP

Tags: php, mixpanel

I want to get data specific of a user on Mixpanel through their PHP API. For example, I want to know that how many times user X did the event AppLauch ?

```
$mp = new Mixpanel($api_key,$api_secret);

//Create single point array with API endpoint
$endpoint = array('segmentation');

//Create array of properties to send
$parameters = array(
'event' => 'AppLaunch', 
'user_id' =>'X',
'from_date' => '2012-12-10', 
'to_date' => '2012-12-12'
 );

 //Make the request

 $data = $mp->request($endpoint, $parameters);
 print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>Take a look at the query made on the Explore page when you click on a user.</s>

```
$endpoint = array('stream', 'query');

$parameters = array(
    'distinct_ids' => json_encode(array('X')),
    'from_date' => '2012-12-10', 
    'to_date' => '2012-12-12'
);
```

EDIT: Streams is dead.

Comment: I could not find this on the documentation but it works really well.

Comment: Just a heads up, was looking to use this to replicate the People page in Custom Reports, and it looks like they've locked this Stream API down. Came here pretty excited to see someone else had watched the network traffic to see the Stream endpoint, but this is a no-go now.

Comment: Streams is a dead product now; go reverse the live view API :)